# JUnitParamsRunner with Guice

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, guice, junitparams

I have a java test which is based on guice. I want to pass multiple parameter sets which are supported by `JUnitParams`. But it looks like I can pass only one `@RunWith`. So essentially I can add either `JUnitParamsRunner` or `GuiceTestRunner`. What is the way out?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot have multiple runners for one test class - this is a limitation of JUnit 4. You can however have a runner and multiple [`Rule`](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/rules)s. There is no official `Rule` for Guice, but you can find a few third-party solutions (eg. [here](https://gist.github.com/nlativy/a39273ef3ad268ab77eb) or [here](https://github.com/ctrimble/junit-guice)) or write your own. That way you can have a test class that is annotated with `@RunWith(JUnitParamsRunner.class)` and has a `@Rule` field that sets up Guice.